# Event listeners in React/Redux in separate file (electron)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron, flux

So I have a React/electron application. Sometimes my `main.js` file sends some data over, via ipc. Up until now I had my React components send & wait for certain ipc events like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ipcRenderer.send('sendTranslateRequest', "Bonjour mon amour");
    ipcRenderer.on('receiveTranslateResponse', (evt, arg) => {
           //... });
}
```

However, as I am using Redux now I found myself thinking a bit more about my apps architecture. Would it not be a good idea to create a separate file and put all my listeners into it, and whenever a listener is activated, to dispatch a Redux action. And likewise, to put all my `ipcRenderer.send`s into the respective Redux actions, so that my React Components are completely clear from all of that?

Would this be possible? And: Would this be a good idea?

I am wondering how I could create a file which has the ability to take all my listeners. So I would have a file like this:

```
ipcRenderer.on('receiveTranslateResponse', (evt, arg) => {
    //dispatch actions then
    });
ipcRenderer.on('receiveAnotherResponse', (evt, arg) => {
    //dispatch actions then
    });
```

What I don't understand is how I could include this file into my React application, how & where to execute it?

Comment: did you got the solution?